# How to replace values in column A with column B with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, replace

My dataframe lists some of the name I interested and may make some changes, what I want is keep the original name if option is blank, delete the name if it says delete and replace the name if it has something.

| name | option |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B | delete |
| C |  |
| D | DDDD |
| E | delete |
| F | FF |

The final dataframe I want is to change the names in a much more big dataframe and with other infos. may look like this

| name | info1 | info2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | xxxx | sth |
| A | xxxx | sth |
| C | x | blala |
| DDDD | xx | lalalaa |
| DDDD | xx | laa |
| DDDD | xx | laaaa |
| FF | xxx | aaaa |

Comment: Could you add your expected output for the above dataframe?

Comment: @Shaido I've added the expected output

Comment: @dewinterbinich - How looks input data and expected ouput? Now it no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For good performance first remove unnecessary rows and then set values by condition:

```
df1 = df[~df['option'].str.contains('delete')]
df1.loc[df['option'].ne('') | df['option'].notnull(), 'name'] = ''
```

Or:

```
df1['name'] = np.where(df['option'].ne('') | df['option'].notnull(), '', df1['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case condition to replace based on option value.

```
val df = Seq(("A", ""), ("B", "delete"), ("C", ""), ("D", "DDDD"), ("E", "delete"), ("F", "FF")).toDF("name", "option")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")

val query = """
select case when option = 'delete' then ''
            when option == '' then name
            else option
       end as name,
       option
from temp
"""
spark.sql(query).show()


+----+------+
|name|option|
+----+------+
|   A|      |
|    |delete|
|   C|      |
|DDDD|  DDDD|
|    |delete|
|  FF|    FF|
+----+------+
```